# How to format timestamp in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to filter date from timestamp in Django template ,
(**Input:**)`2019-03-23T18:51:05.253658` to (**Output:**)`2019-03-23` .Anyone please help me on this?

Comment: which format you want

Comment: i want to filter date from timestamp : 2019-03-23

Comment: wait i will post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First You need to update settings.py**

**`settings.py`**

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]
```

**`Forms.py`**

```
FromDate = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d %b %Y'], widget=forms.DateInput(
        attrs=
        {
        'class'                         : "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12

        }
        ))
```

In **input_formats** you can change Date 
format

Answer (score 4):

Solution above is great, but if you need better flexibility you can use django `date` filter. Example:

```
{{ variable|date:"D d M Y" }}
# result Fri 01 Dec 2019
```

Read more about `date` filter in here:
[Django date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date)